# why form submit returns the text from an select option

Tags: php, html, html-select

why is returning the text when i submit an select post

I have this code

```
<select name="id_comercial" id="id_comercial" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected">Select Comercial</option>
    <option value="1">Comercials</option>
</select>
```

When i submit with the first option
in PHP returns "Select Comercial"
at

```
echo $_POST['id_comercial']
```

returning value = Select Comercial

How can i make my html to return NULL or FALSE or something else but the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <option value="NULL" selected="selected">Select Comercial</option>
```

:)

Comment: That would return a literal string "NULL", not a real null value. Just setting the value attribute is enough, like this:  `<option selected="selected" value>Select Commercial</option>`.

Comment: i made something like that, but everytime i have a string "NULL" then i put input = NULL manually